# Project Euler 12 in java using while loop

Tags: java

I want to solve Project Euler [Problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) by this way but am getting some problem can any one tell me where i am making mistake.

**PROBLEM -

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

```
 1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Problem12 {
int j=1;
static int num; 
List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void trangule(int i){
 num= i*(i+1)/2;    
while(j>0);
{
   for(j =1; j<num/2; j++){
   if(num%j==0)
    {int temp= num/j;

    ls.add(temp);
    }
   if(ls.size()==500)
   {
    System.out.println(ls.get(ls.size()-1));   
   }   
   }


}

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Problem12 ob =new Problem12();
 for(int i =1; i<=500; i++) 
 { ob.trangule(i);}

}

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any thing.  Is my logic is wrong ? I saw other solutions on net but am not getting those ...

Comment: show what output you are getting. you are printing num in the main method, what is the output of that?

Comment: i am trying to get System.out.println(ls.get(ls.size()-1))

Comment: your loop isn't even being executed.

Comment: How to check it even i am not getting any thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a null-statement `while` loop:

```
while(j>0);
```

The `;` ends the loop, so it is constantly cycling on the condition `j>0` which is always true, so the code will never get past that point.

I'm not sure what that `while` loop is for in the first place, even if you remove `;` it's still never going to leave that loop.  In fact I don't think you need it.

Some other things to note:

- The question asked in the problem is "What is the value of the first triangle number to have **over** five hundred divisors?" The first one to be over five hundred won't necessarily have exactly 500 divisors, which is your current check.
- You are not clearing out `ls` between iterations, so the `ArrayList` will continue to accumulate factors from all of the triangle numbers combined (you can use [ArrayList#clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) to do this)